# Matplotlib plots (0,0) even though there is no NaN or NULL value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I use matplotlib to plot multilple lines with different color each. And it works quite nicely but somehow all of the plotted lines connects to (0,0) for the last value.

X-axis: `bin`which are my timeframes 
 Y-axis: `count` which contain the values I'd like to plot

My dataframe looks like this:

```
>df3.head()
           start_time  count    date_day       bin  cw
0 2016-05-02 00:00:00     45  2016-05-02  00:00:00  18
1 2016-05-02 00:15:00     35  2016-05-02  00:15:00  18
2 2016-05-02 00:30:00     34  2016-05-02  00:30:00  18
3 2016-05-02 00:45:00     31  2016-05-02  00:45:00  18
4 2016-05-02 01:00:00     34  2016-05-02  01:00:00  18

>df3.tail()
               start_time  count    date_day       bin  cw
17563 2016-10-31 22:45:00    114  2016-10-31  22:45:00  44
17564 2016-10-31 23:00:00     94  2016-10-31  23:00:00  44
17565 2016-10-31 23:15:00    121  2016-10-31  23:15:00  44
17566 2016-10-31 23:30:00    127  2016-10-31  23:30:00  44
17567 2016-10-31 23:45:00    135  2016-10-31  23:45:00  44
```

This is how I plot:
I seperate the lines by calendar week `cw`

```
cw = np.arange(18,45,1)
for x in cw:
    df4 = df3[df3.cw == x]
    xa = df4['bin']
    ya = df4['count']
    plt.plot(xa, ya)
plt.show()
```

What I get is this:
[Plot (labels and axis are not formatted yet..)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMNev.png)
[image]

For `df3.any().isnull()` I don't get any NaN which should be ok, but it still plots (0,0).

```
df3.any().isnull()
Out[297]: 

start_time    False
count         False
date_day      False
bin           False
cw            False
dtype: bool
```

Any ideas how I can get rid of this Connection line to (0,0)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: First quick guess: You are trying to plot the times over the whole 7 days of a week, but in the plot you only see the data from one single day. Does that make sense to you? What would you like to happen with the data of the other 6 days?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. My DataFrame only contains Mondays. I just used `cw`to separate the lines because I had no clue how to separate or slice my data at first since `start_time` is continuous (mondays only though) but my `bin` column is a repeating sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution: I was a little bit too careless when slicing my data.

I sliced my data set for all Mondays (`df.weekday == 0`). THEN I grouped my Monday data in 15-min-bins with `pandas.Grouper`. 
 
And here's the error: `Grouper` is grouping in between the maximum range which is found in the `start_time` column and consequently brings back all days in between my start-date and end-date. So I had many zero values which explains my plot.
Somehow I failed checking for this issue. Thanks for your time though!